# Why is my OpenGL code failing?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

Please keep in mind that I am new to android development and I have no experience of using OpenGL before.
I followed this lesson:
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html

and my current code is:

OpenGLESTestActivity.java:

```
package com.KML;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.opengl.*;

import com.KML.MyGLRenderer;

public class OpenGLESTestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }
}

class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {


    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setRenderer(new MyGLRenderer());
        this.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        this.setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }
}
```

in MyGLRenderer.java:

```
package com.KML;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;


public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

}
```

This is giving me "Unfortunately, OpenGLESTest has stopped." on my android device.

Thanks

Comment: Post the exception my dear friend!

Comment: It may be, that your device doesn't support OpenGL ES 2.0, but please send a log for sure.

Comment: If you are using the emulator, you might not have Graphics Rendering or OpenGL activated (something like that). Older versions of the emulator did not support OpenGL stuff.

Comment: sorry, this may sound really noobish, but how do I get the error log?
And I am testing it on my Transformer Prime. I read somewhere that the emulator doesn't support OpenGL, and the emulator is super slow anyway..

Comment: What is your development environment? If you're using eclipse, it usually appears in a small window called "LogCat". After the crash you should see a block of red text about 20-50 lines long which says what caused the crash. If you don't use eclipse, I know you can get the logcat from `adb`, but I don't know the exact command. Try `adb -help` (or some such help command)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenGLES on Android - IllegalStateException: setRenderer has already been called for this instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301468/opengles-on-android-illegalstateexception-setrenderer-has-already-been-called)

```
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) 
{
    super(context);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer (new MyRenderer());
    setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
}
```

It's the order you are setting up everything that is wrong.