# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Layoutinflater.class

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an android application that uses google maps api version 2.
In Debug the application crashes when it executes the instruction:

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_map);
```

This is the error:

> the source attachment does not contain the source for the file
>   Layoutinflater.class

I don't understand the reason. In headers I imported the whole class

```
android.view.*
```

Thank you in advance for any answer.

This is the code:

```
public class PoiMap extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap pMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent callerIntent = getIntent();
        final LatLng userCoord = callerIntent.getParcelableExtra("userCoord");
        final Poi poi = (Poi) callerIntent.getSerializableExtra("poi");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_poi_map);
        setUpMapIfNeeded(userCoord);

        // Sets a callback that's invoked when the camera changes.
        pMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

            @Override
            /* Only use the simpler method newLatLngBounds(boundary, padding) to generate 
             * a CameraUpdate if it is going to be used to move the camera *after* the map 
             * has undergone layout. During layout, the API calculates the display boundaries 
             * of the map which are needed to correctly project the bounding box. 
             * In comparison, you can use the CameraUpdate returned by the more complex method 
             * newLatLngBounds(boundary, width, height, padding) at any time, even before the 
             * map has undergone layout, because the API calculates the display boundaries 
             * from the arguments that you pass. 
             * @see com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener#onCameraChange(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition)
             */
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                // Move camera.
                if (poi != null){
                    LatLng poiCoord = poi.getLatLng();
                    pMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(poiCoord)
                    .title(poi.getName())
                    .snippet(poi.getCategory())
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_star)));

                    Log.d("userCoord", userCoord.toString());
                    Log.d("poiCoord", poiCoord.toString());

                    double minY = Math.min(userCoord.latitude, poiCoord.latitude);
                    double minX = Math.min(userCoord.longitude, poiCoord.longitude);
                    double maxY = Math.max(userCoord.latitude, poiCoord.latitude);
                    double maxX = Math.max(userCoord.longitude, poiCoord.longitude);

                    Log.d("minY", " " + minY);
                    Log.d("minX", " " + minX);
                    Log.d("maxY", " " + maxY);
                    Log.d("maxX", " " + maxX);

                    LatLng northEast = new LatLng(maxY, maxX);
                    LatLng southWest = new LatLng(minY, minX);
                    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

                    // move camera
                    pMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 40));

                    // Remove listener to prevent position reset on camera move.
                    pMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_poi_map, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded(new LatLng(0.0, 0.0));
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded(LatLng coord) {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (pMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            pMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (pMap != null) {
                setUpMap(coord);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap(LatLng userCoord) {
        pMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(userCoord)
                            .title("Your location")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_user)));
        pMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userCoord));

        /* public static CameraUpdate newLatLngZoom (LatLng latLng, float zoom) 
         * Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the center of the screen to a latitude 
         * and longitude specified by a LatLng object, and moves to the given zoom 
         * level.
         * Parameters
         * latLng   a LatLng object containing the desired latitude and longitude.
         * zoom     the desired zoom level, in the range of 2.0 to 21.0. 
         * Values below this range are set to 2.0, and values above it are set to 21.0. 
         * Increase the value to zoom in. Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom levels.
         * Returns
         * a CameraUpdate containing the transformation. 
*/
        pMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userCoord, 15));

    }

}
```

Comment: That is not the reason the app crashed, read the red LogCat lines the stack trace. What you are seeing simply means your haven't linked your project to the Android source code (this is not necessary to write an app.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question and I can never find a good answer for anyone so I'll do my best to help.

This sounds like you are missing the source code for Android. You need to download the **Sources for Android SDK** in Eclipse with the **SDK Manager**.

1. Open the **SDK Manager** in Eclipse
2. Find the version of android you want the source for. In this example, **Android 4.2 (API17)**
3. Check the box **Sources for Android SDK**
4. Click **Install # packages**

For example

[image]

After that, run your program and get to the point that you get that error. Now you will need to attach the documentation you've downloaded

**Short**

1. Click the button **Edit Source Lookup Path**
2. Click the **Default** folder
3. Click **Add**
4. Select **File System Directory** and click **OK**
5. Locate your downloaded source code. In this example, look for *android-17* for API17. It will be in a directory such as `adt-bundle\sdk\sources\android-17`
6. Click OK a few times and your source is now linked.

**Long**

Click the button **Edit Source Lookup Path**

[image]

Click the **Default** folder and click **Add**

[image]

Select **File System Directory** and click **OK**

[image]

Locate your downloaded source code. In this example, look for *android-17* for API17. It will be in a directory such as `adt-bundle\sdk\sources\android-17`

[image]

Click **OK** twice and it should look something like this

[image]

Click **OK** and enjoy your source code

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that you are unable to access the source code whose bytecode is being called. In order to list out the exception you would need the original source which unfortunately is usually unavailable in jar formats.

Your option is to update the .jar file by updating your Android SDK with correct Rev’s and let it compile again to fix the issue.