# Source not found classloader.class

Tags: android, eclipse

I wrote the following code for reading information from an internet source:

```
public String ReadUrl(){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String result = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(this.url);
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return result;
}
```

`this.url` looks like: `"http://example.com/json.php"`. When I want to open this application on a virtual machine I get this error in Eclipse:

> The source attachment does not contain the source for the file classloader.class

Where is the problem? (I updated Eclipse and Android SDK).

Comment: Please, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942851/the-source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-layoutinflater-cl