# Debugging Android in Eclipse; What cause Source not found error

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

When opening another activity, this error comes:

Class File Editor

Source not found

The source attachment does not contain the source file View.class

I tried so many solution that were provided here and this one also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdIZ7r2d4J4

How to fix this ?

Comment: There's nothing to fix.  You don't have the source code for the `View` class because it's pre-compiled into the Android SDK.  `View` is part of the Android system.  Why do you need to see the source code during debugging anyway?  Even if it's not working properly (which is unlikely) you can't do anything about it.  If you want to look at the source code, you can do so here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/view/View.java/

Comment: LogCat : http://tinypic.com/r/2lld7ia/8

Comment: When I open Eclipse I got : http://tinypic.com/r/2ef25pl/8

Comment: Dear @SDJMcHattie I got the error while debugging, running doesn't show any errors it only freeze the page when I hit the button (which supposed to open another activity), all my project works great for the same function and SDK sources I don't know why this happen suddenly !!

Comment: Are you trying to see what's wrong by double clicking the first item in the stack trace?  Sometimes the first item is the Android system itself throwing an exception when calling a built in method.  You should scan down the stack trace until you find one of your own classes.  The one nearest the top will be calling a system method like `startActivity()` but passing some data that the system can't handle and so an exception is later thrown by the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow the steps of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942851/the-source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-layoutinflater-cl) answer and it works :)

Thank you everyone.