# Error source attachment does not contain the source for the file parse.class

Tags: java, android

I've encountered the above error when i try to access parse. I've imported the relevant JAR files into my project. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942851/the-source-attachment-does-not-contain-the-source-for-the-file-layoutinflater-cl) is related with your question.

> This usually means that you are unable to access the source code whose
> bytecode is being called.
> ....
>
> Your option is to update the .jar file by updating your Android SDK
> with correct Rev’s and let it compile again to fix the issue.