# fragmentmanager.class not found during debugging in eclipse for android

Tags: android, debugging

im trying to debug an android app but during a "STEP OVER" click the eclipse jumps to fragmentclass.class and it shows Source not found and i can't continue debugging.

what could be the problem ?

Comment: you should set sources of sdk for looking SDK classes

Answer (score 0):

1. Project Properties
2. Java Build Path - Libraries
3. Set Source attachment (here set path to sources of sdk)

[image: Java build path]

Also, look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943825/1991579)

Comment: thanks  , however when I try to install this new software I am getting an error . are you familiar with this ?
http://s11.postimg.org/4d8hek4c3/error.jpg